# How to test when a react component render fails

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, chai

For example if `TestFailComponent` tries to access `item.id`, but item is `null`:

```
describe("Should Fail Tests", () => {
  describe("render tests", () => {
    it("should fail to render since null has no id", () => {
      let shouldFail = mount(
        <MemoryRouter>
          <TestFailComponent
            item={null} />
        </MemoryRouter>
      );
      chai.expect(shouldFail.render).to.throw(new TypeError('null has no properties'))
    });

  });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
chai.expect(shouldFail.exists()).to.be.false()
chai.expect(shouldFail.render).to.be.null()
```

related:

- [Test whether React component has rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40869042/test-whether-react-component-has-rendered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create error boundary component to test it.
Complete file, which works is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

// assume this component we want to test
const TestFailComponent = ({ items }) => {
    if (items == null) {
        throw new TypeError('null has no properties');
    }
    return 'hello world';
};

// We create a component-helper
class ErrorCatching extends React.Component {
    state = { hasError: false };
    // we need to change state, so that render cycle could be completed
    static getDerivedStateFromError() {        
        return { hasError: true };
    }
    // catch error and test it
    componentDidCatch(error, errInfo) {        
        // we even can check componentStack field into errInfo arg
        this.props.processError(error, errInfo);
    }
    render() {
        // after the first error we render nothing
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return null;
        }
        return this.props.children;
    }
}

describe('Should Fail Tests', () => {
    describe('render tests', () => {
        it('should fail to render since null has no id', () => {
            // our expected error
            const expectedError = new TypeError('null has no properties');

            mount(
                <ErrorCatching processError={(error) => expect(error).toEqual(expectedError)}>
                    <TestFailComponent item={null} />
                </ErrorCatching>
            );
        });
    });
});
```

You also can check the result of the render which will be null.

More about error handling:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#error-boundaries and https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/07/26/error-handling-in-react-16.html#targetText=Error%20boundaries%20are%20React%20components,the%20whole%20tree%20below%20them.

Comment: Very concise. Thanks so much, I was really having a hard time finding how to do this.

Comment: Just one thing had `tslint` throw an error about `Declaration of public static method not allowed after declaration of public instance field. Instead, this should come at the beginning of the class/interface.` Moving the declaration of `state` to be after the `static  getDerivedStateFromError` resolved the linting error. Thanks again.